# Bluetooth just up and vanished

Tags: windows-11, bluetooth

A few days ago, my mouse and keyboard (both of which are Bluetooth) just stopped working.  I don't believe there were any Windows updates around that time, so I'm not entirely sure what happened.  I had to plug in the USB dongle as a workaround, but now I can't use my Bluetooth headphones either.

If I click on the connection property thing in the system tray, I no longer see any Bluetooth options:

[image]

If I go to Bluetooth connections, there's no option to turn it on or off anymore:

[image]

If I run the Bluetooth troubleshooting wizard, I get the following:

[image]

The system definitely has Bluetooth.  I've been using it for ages.

The device manager doesn't appear to have any drivers for Bluetooth:

[image]

Any other tips to get Bluetooth working again?

OS information:

[image]

Thanks!